# Magento: Checkbox is showing unchecked after checked and saved in admin configuration

Tags: magento-1.9, configuration, system.xml

I created a checkout in system.xml in admin configuration. When I check that checkbox and click on save config, then 1 is storing in `core_config_data` but checkbox is still unchecked. How to checked ?

Answer (score 0):

i have faced same issue but not able to solve this.

I tried to put some js that when the checkbox change set the input value according to this and when the page load does the opposite ... This doesn't work.

alternative solution: use a `dropdown`

```
 <terms_and_condition translate="label">
                <label>Use terms and condition</label>
                <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>                                                                     
                <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>     
                <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
               <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
 </terms_and_condition >
```

hope this will solve your issue

Comment: I need to use checkbox only , i can't use select at place of checkbox .

Comment: @ShubhamS, Best of luck. post your answer as well when you achieve this.